# Right Cisco switch for iSCSI SAN network

Tags: cisco, switch, hp, san, iscsi

I'm trying to revive this old HP P4500 Lefthand SAN and recover some data from it. There was a pair of Cisco switches configured for the SAN traffic. Those are no longer there. All I have access to are the vmware host and the SAN nodes where all the vm's were stored.

Trying to re-build the network and acquire some old inexpensive switches that will do the job. Looking at These three switches from a local seller

```
Ws-c2950-24
Ws-c2960-24tt-L
Ws-c2950t-48-si
```

Would you kind network experts please help determine if any of these work for me? I understand I need to find a cisco expert to help configure these switches but I would like to have the hardware first as I'm getting a deal from the local seller.

Trying to do this without spending a lot. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Those switches you have listed are very old. I would look for something a bit newer to be honest.

Comment: If it's not for production, pretty much any switch does it... You could even run with a single port. For production, a SAN should be thoroughly designed, not with old hardware. What are the requirements?

Comment: The soul purpose is to connect things and extract data. this is not a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2950's are too slow, and their buffers *way* too small for iSCSI. 2960's will work in a pinch, but their buffers are really small as well. (I've run iSCSI SANs on 2960S's. For low traffic levels it will work; at higher levels frame drops will become a nightmare.)

Comment: I ended up with a 2960 and a 2950. $20 each. Are you or anyone here able to give me some guidance on configuring these switches and getting the SAN up and running? I can deal with the slow transfer as all I'm doing is extracting some data.

Comment: @Eclipse Configure access password, enable flow control and portfast on the iSCSI ports. If you interconnect with your LAN you need to set up VLANs appropriately.

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks for your response. I have no experience with Cisco equipment. Any article or howto for this specific scenario? If you can provide paid help for this, we can do that as well.

Comment: @Eclipse That'll not be necessary. Do you have any documentation how the ports were mapped (ie. the IP addresses and masks)? How many host ports do you need to connect? You should add this info to your question.

Comment: @Zac67 unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation or backup for the previous config. what are my options? can it be reverse engineered from each node network config?

Comment: @eclipse That should be possible. What's the network config on the array ports and the host VMkernel adapters?